# How to Encrypt the Search String and Search that Encrypted word in Encrypted Doc in Android

Tags: android, encryption

I am new to android development ,My question is can i search encrypted string in  encrypted file .In brief when i give a search term first it is encrypted and searches for the required term in encrypted file.I searched google but find nothing in java or android one related what i found is:
[Encrypted Search](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/01/23/searching-encrypted-data/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can I would suggest decrypting the data, storing it in memory, and disposing of it when finished. If that option isn't available I would suggest looking into [Homomorphic encryption](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/hacker-lexicon-homomorphic-encryption/). The algorithm was developed by some IBM guys but is still highly experimental and only advised for research. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It definitely depends on the encryption you are using.  As Zack Matthews mentioned, there is Homomorphic encryption designed to make this and other operations on encrypted information possible.  But for simpler, more common types of encryption, it is not that simple.  Even in ECB mode (which is not secure precisely because it has the property you are looking for in a limited sense) block ciphers like AES, Twofish, and Serpent, which usually have 128 bit blocks, but sometimes 64 bit, will have the same plain text yield the same cipher text only if every byte in that 16 byte block is identical to the bytes you are looking for.  Flip one bit in the plain text, and the cipher text will be different throughout the entire block.

It gets worse with CBC mode.  This mode has an XOR feedback which virtually guarantees the same plain text will never yield the same cipher text, even if that plain text appears repeatedly in the same document.